# Website address ending in colon giving server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

When I have a website address like http://www.websiteaddress2323.com/info/Value23:

the website is giving HTTP 500 Internal Server Error because the address is ending with colon `:`

I added the following in the web.config so that any links after the path is valid

```
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler1" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler,   
   System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,          Culture=neutral,          
   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" path="/info/*" verb="GET" />
```

This works on my localhost server, but when I push it out to Azure, it is giving the 500 Internal Server Error.

Is there anyway to fix this? What I want to do is permanent rewrite the address to `/info/Value23` by removing the colon, but the page load module is not getting called and throws the error before it had the chance to call the page_load code so that I can catch this address and redirect.

Comment: What output you're expecting? Any database results? I think it has something to do with the database connectivity. debug it using httpfox (firefox) can reveal something in that driection

Comment: This is a web server error. It is not allowing URLs that contain colons (:) to pass through and gives 500 Internal Server Error. The webpage is not being reached.

Answer (score 0):

If there is colon at last, then webserver is expecting a Port number, that's why its giving you Server Error.

Here is URL details
http://www.utoronto.com/webdocs/HTMLdocs/NewHTML/url.html

For correct url, either you will need to provide Port number or remove Colon